# windows 7 - set system volume for application without it running

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have a game executing via steam that is a port from an old Windows 95/98 game. For some reason, alt-tab does not work in this game, so I cannot move to the Desktop while it's running. Unfortunately the game is uncomfortably loud even with all volume controls set next to 0 inside the game, which is why I would like to lower the system volume for that specific application. Is there a way to set the system volume for an application while the application is not running?

Comment: You should still be able to hit CTRL-ALT-DEL while in that game as it overrides everything, even alt-tab. This should allow you to start a task manager, and from there you might be able to go to the desktop, to access the volume mixer to set the volume for that specific game.

Comment: @LPChip Unfortunately, that doesn't work either; I get to the "choose what to do" screen and can choose the task manager, but that just opens it and releases the control back to the game.

Comment: Hmm odd. Is it possible to go into windowed mode? For example by pressing ALT-ENTER, or through the in-game options?

Comment: @LPChip There are no ingame-options with respect to windowed or non-windowed. alt+enter does not work either, unfortunately.